# Android camera, activity destroyed on GS4

Tags: android, android-camera

so here is my simple code:

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.slidingMenu.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

invoking camera:

```
private void startCamera() {

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, cameraData); 
}
```

so the problem is, this works fine on older devices like galaxy ace, or galaxy s2, but when tested on a GS4, the main activity gets killed and recreated again, any one knows about this issue ?

NB: 
The weird thing is the activity gets killed ONLY when I take a picture, if I don't and come back, it works fine

thanks !

Comment: Yep, normal behaviour.  Read about the Activity life cycle.  The easiest way to do this is to assume that the next callback after onPause() might be onCreate().  If you code like this, you'll never have a problem!

Comment: thanks, but here the activity gets killed, so it starts all over, and it starts from fragment 0, I lose all the back stack

Comment: Depending on the Android version, your activity might be destroyed or your entire app process might be killed.  The reason you only see it when you take a photo is because the memory requirement for the camera app goes up and Android frees some memory. I already know from your manifest that you are using a bad hack to stop your Activity from being recreated on orientation change so I suspect that your onCreate(), onResume() and onPause() methods have not been correctly written.  First thing to do is to remove that hack (android:configChanges) then fix the bugs.Your problem will get fixed too.

Comment: about the back stack, I meant that my activity hosts some fragments so they all get destroyed, thanks for your answer i'll try to make it work

Comment: I am facing this issue in galaxy s3

Answer (score 0):

> android:screenOrientation="portrait" remove this attribute and check

Comment: that didn't do it, the weird thing is the activity gets killed ONLY when I take a picture, if I don't and come back, it works fine

Comment: try removing android:launchMode="singleTask" also

Comment: Do you find any solution. I recently found this issue on GS1 mobile.